# Deep doubt on a double surface integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, surface-integrals, parametrization

I don't understand how to proceed with an exercise. I will write down what I have done so far.

The exercise is:

> Evaluate the following integral $$\iint_{\Sigma}\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\ \text{d}\sigma $$
>
> Where $\Sigma = \{(x, y, z): x^2+ y^2 = z^2+1,\ 1\leq z \leq 2 \}$

**My attempt**

I wrote

$$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2-1} ~~~~~~~ \text{with} ~~~~~~~ 2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 5$$

Hence I fond a parametrisation curve like

$$\phi: \begin{cases}
x = t \\
y = s \\
z = \sqrt{t^2+s^2-1}
\end{cases}
$$

Now I have to calculate the vector product of the partial derivatives gradients (I know I am expressing myself in a bad language, I apologise):

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \left(1,\ 0,\ \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+s^2-1}}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial s} = \left(0,\ 1,\ \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{t^2+s^2-1}}\right)$$

Hence

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \text{det}\begin{pmatrix}
i & j & k \\
1 & 0 & \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+s^2-1}} \\
0 & 1 & \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{t^2+s^2-1}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which lead me to

$$\bigg|\bigg| \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} \wedge \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\bigg|\bigg| = 
\sqrt{\dfrac{2(t^2+s^2)-1}{t^2+s^2-1}}
$$

Now I should evaluate the integral but I don't know how to proceed since I would get

$$\iint_{\Sigma} \dfrac{1}{s^2+t^2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2(t^2+s^2)-1}{t^2+s^2-1}}\ \text{d}\sigma\ \text{d}s$$

And I cannot continue...

I should get $3\pi$ as a result. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the answer is 3$\pi$? I don't think that's true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy if you use the fact that $\Sigma$ have rotational symmetry around $z$ axis :

$$\iint_\Sigma\frac{d\sigma}{x^2+y^2}=\iint_\Sigma\frac{d\sigma}{z^2+1}=\int_1^2\frac{2\pi\sqrt{z^2+1}}{z^2+1}\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{d(\sqrt{z^2+1})}{dz}\bigg)^2}dz$$$$=2\pi\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{2z^2+1}}{z^2+1}dz.$$

However, I don't think 3$\pi$ is the value of the integral. When I did numerical calculation of this integral, it gave me approx. $4.5595$, which clearly is not $3\pi$. Also Mathematica yields : $$2\pi\int_1^2\frac{\sqrt{2z^2+1}}{z^2+1}dz=\pi\bigg(2\sqrt{2}\Big(\arcsin(2\sqrt{2})-\arcsin(\sqrt{2})\Big)+\log((2+\sqrt{3})/5)\bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you so much. The professor was wrong!